# Kafka Connect SMT with cache value lookup

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm using a Kafka Connect sink connector to read events from Kafka and insert them into a database.
Some events contain references in their value payload. I want to use an SMT to resolve these references with a cache lookup to replace them within the value payload with their referenced entity.

E.g.: value payload transformed from `{id: 12}` to `{name: "the-referenced-entity}` where the cache is `{12: "the-referenced-entity", ...}`

Thinking about solutions:

- The problem I see with **SMTs** is that I have no way to share state between different records so e.g. every time I apply the transformation I would have to rebuild the cache (=slow). SMTs are stateless/pure.
- I could use an **external cache** (e.g. Redis) but this would still introduce some network latency (=slow?).
- I could work around Kafka Connect of course and create my own **custom consumer**, but I would lose a lot of the nicities that Kafka Connect offers then.

Are there known best practices for this use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to share some cache, you could run some distributed database on the host of each worker. Then it would only be a local network call, not a remote one.

Otherwise, just produce the ID as-is. Use Kafka Streams / ksqlDB, for example to do a Stream-Table join operation, where the ID can be translated. (That KStream job could also be ran on the Connect workers)